# Распарсить Whois IP

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Необходимо узнать оператора и страну посетителя.

Воспользовался   Whois:

```
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    function whois($ip) {
        $sock = fsockopen ("whois.ripe.net",43,$errno,$errstr);
        if (!$sock) {
            echo("$errno($errstr)");
            return;
        }
        else {
            fputs ($sock, $ip."\r\n");
            while (!feof($sock)) {
               echo (str_replace(":",": ",fgets ($sock,128))."<br>");
            }
        }
        fclose ($sock);
    }
echo (whois($ip));
```

На выходе получаю список с инфой, нужно вычленить оттуда нужные пары значений.
Если кто знает другой способ определения оператора посетителя и/или базы принадлежности Ip операторам, буду безмерно благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ip = '8.8.8.8';
$geo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.2ip.com.ua/geo.json?ip={$ip}"),true);
$provider = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.2ip.com.ua/provider.json?ip={$ip}"),true);

print_r($geo);
print_r($provider);
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое за более удобный вариант)

Comment: @Broouzer King, не за что :)